# threading to output fast actions discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As a proof of concept im trying to integrate multithreading with discord.py, but when i run this code im getting an error ive never seen before. does anyone know how to make this work?
error: TypeError: create() missing 1 required posistional argument 'ctx'

here is a snapshot of the relevant part of the code.

````
async def create(ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        amount = 150
        for i in range(amount):
           await guild.create_text_channel("channel")

init()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"""
threading test discord.py

prefix: {Fore.GREEN}$
    """)

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=create)
    thread1.start()





client.run(token)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`create` is an asynchronous function, threading does not work with them, a solution might be to use the `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` method:

```py
import asyncio

def create(ctx):
    async def create(ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        amount = 150
        for i in range(amount):
            await guild.create_text_channel("channel")
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(create(ctx), loop)
    return fut.result()


# inside command
thread = threading.Thread(target=create, args=(ctx,))
thread.start()
```

You can make a decorator for simplicity:

```py
from functools import wraps
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def coro_to_thread(fn):  # the decorator
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            fn(*args, **kwargs), loop
        )
        return fut.result()
    return wrapper


@coro_to_thread
async def create(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    amount = 150
    for i in range(amount):
        await guild.create_text_channel("channel")


# inside command
thread = threading.Thread(target=create, args=(ctx,))
thread.start()
```

Comment: i tried running the code up at the top you sent and im getting an error
"TypeError: __main__.create() argument after * must be an iterable, not Context"

Comment: Remember to put the comma when passing the arguments to the thread, not `(ctx)` but `(ctx,)`